# Google Search asks for my location once a day on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, safari, search, geolocation, google

On my iPhone, when I perform a search on Google in Safari, once a day it will ask for my location. So, it won't ask for that day, and then the next day, when I perform a Google search, it will ask for my location again. It seems to ask for my location even if I perform a search that doesn't even require my location.

I want Google to permanently remember my location, or at least stop asking me for my location at all.

I have already tried going to the Google homepage and clicking on the "Use precise location" link to try to get it to remember my location, but that didn't work.

I've also tried clearing all Safari iOS data.

Comment: Not sure this is an option for you, but have you tried setting Settings > Privacy > Location Services > Safari Websites to "Never"?

Comment: I haven't tried that. I assume that would work. But of course ideally, I'd like to be able to continue using location services for Safari for certain websites.